# Angular Protractor e2e testing Multiple Dropdowns

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have Multiple dropdowns in the header part with the same class name. How to write protractor e2e test cases for multiple dropdowns.

This is my HTML Code Snippet:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Patient Flow <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#/patientDashboard/appointments">Patient Portal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/dashboard2/stations/1/patients">Patient Queue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/dashboard4/appointments">Visitor Dashboard</a></li>
            <!--  <li><a href="#/patientDashboard/appointments">Patient List View</a></li> -->
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#/dashboard3/encounters">OR Flow</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Track Assets <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#/listViewTable/assets">Asset List View</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/dashboard5/assets">Asset Map View</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">System Setup <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#/listViewTable/patients">Patients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/listViewTable/appointments">Appointments</a></li>
          </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#/dashboard10/encounters/1">Reports</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var dropdown = element.all(by.css('.dropdown')).get(N);
var toggle = dropdown.element(by.css('.dropdown-toggle'));
toggle.click();
var list = dropdown.all(by.css('.dropdown-menu li'));
expect(list.first().getText()).toEqual('Patient Portal');
```

to get the Nth dropdown ([Doc](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get)), and test the first element of it...

Then for this kind of quite complex page, I suggest to use [Page objects](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/page-objects).

[Edit: Also, I don't know if it's a good practice, but if you don't want to be stuck to a specific order, I would add a unique class on each dropdown (or an ID)]

Comment: What is get(N) in the first line.

Comment: N is the number of the element you want to access. For instance, if you want the first, you have to do get(0) (or first()), if you want to second dropdown, then you do get(1), etc.